# Excel VBA Screen Updating - Update Only One Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs for about a minute and loads/processes a lot of data. Naturally I've turned off screen updating so that it runs faster and doesn't jump around all the time. However, I'd like to be able to turn on screen updating/force update one cell.

I can't just do something like:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
<SET VALUE>
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Because when you set screen updating to true, it updates all the changes that have been made since you set it to false. How do I update just that one cell?

Thanks!

Comment: What's in that cell? Is it a calculated value? Depending on your document's setup, you could set calculation state to manual and then calculate that one cell. As far as I know, though, you can't just show a single cell updating in the presence of other changes on the same sheet. You could generate a temporary worksheet for display purposes, but if you're working with a lot of data, this is probably not a viable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Naturally I've turned off screen updating so that it runs faster and
>   doesn't jump around all the time.

The "doesn't jump around all the time" part makes me wonder if you are using `Select` and `Activate` a lot in your code. These are very time-consuming operations and you should be able to achieve most things without them.

Judicious use of the `Range` and/or `Cells` properties of the `Worksheet` in question should be a lot faster than any combination of `Select` and/or `Activate`. If you can speed up your code enough then you may be able to leave `ScreenUpdating` on and thus solve your original problem

Comment: I'm not using select or activate very much. However, I do switch sheets twice, which is a big reason for me to turn off screen updating. However, I wonder if I can remove that and do the same operations but stay on one sheet. That would probably let me turn off screen updating. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tie the cell to a textbox or other control, and let it show the value that you want to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hack, but you could print an error message when the particular cell you want to be notified about is updated or [for something less intrusive] just update the status bar:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub test_screen_updating()
    Range("A1:A10").ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 10
        Range("A" & i).Value = i
        If i = 2 Then
            ' MsgBox "A2 was updated: " + CStr(Range("A2").Value)
            Application.StatusBar = "A2 updated to: " + CStr([A2])
        End If
        Sleep 500
    Next i
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Just make sure you reset the status bar if you update it.

Comment: Yeah I looked at the status bar and Msgbox's, I'd really just like to update the cell on the screen though.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is an issue, can you do:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
<process>
Application.Calculation =xlCalculationAutomatic
```

? That can make a big difference.